# unity-reset on boot - Ubuntu 12.10 Unity Problem

Tags: unity, 12.10

I tried many many workarounds for the unity fix in 12.10 ubuntu version...

I have ATI Mobility Radeon HD3650 graphics card..
I managed to install the 12.6 version of it, and downgrade the X-Server from 1.13 to 1.12.3 using the code below of this guy 'Makarewicz'
Code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```

Now i using `fglrxinfo` i get

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11653 Compatibility Profile Context
```

but still on boot i cant see unity.
However using in a TTY unity or unity-reset, i can have unity, until i reboot...

So is there a way to make this permanent?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add these line to /etc/rc.local. To add them, follow these instruction

Open a terminal and type

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Then paste this line before `exit 0`

```
unity-reset
```

Make it execuable

```
sudo chmod a+x /etc/rc.local
```